# C# How do I line-serially read a RichTextbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a basic RichTextBox called TxtUsernames, via this command
 `TxtUsernames.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\Dokumente\Visual Studio 2015\user.txt", Encoding.Default);`  I read the file into this Textbox.

Now I want the first line to be read and in the next run of my while-do argument the second line and so on.

```
    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal Amount;
        Amount = nudAmount.Value;    // Amount of Accounts to create
        int x;                       // variable used to count how many accounts have been created so far
        x = 0;

        do
        {


            string Emailhost;            // standard is @gmail.com
            Emailhost = TxtEmail.Text;
            var doc = WebBrowser1.Document;

            TxtUsernames.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\Dokumente\Visual Studio 2015\user.txt", Encoding.Default);
            TxtPasswords.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\Dokumente\Visual Studio 2015\pwx.txt", Encoding.Default);

            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("PvpnetAccountName").SetAttribute("value", "Username");

            x++;

        } while (x > Amount);
    }`
```

Instead of  "Username", I want to have the content of line one to be written in there. And in the next run of while do line 2 and so on and so forth.

Comment: Your code will read the entire  text file in every while iteration. And then you want to read just one line, but load all of it every iteration. Sounds very awkward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream for that

```
using (var userNameStream = File.OpenText("user.txt"))
using (var pwdStream = File.OpenText("pwd.txt"))
{
    while (!userNameStream.EndOfStream && !pwdStream.EndOfStream)
    {
        // your logic
        string userName = userNameStream.ReadLine();
        string pwd = pwdStream.ReadLine();
        // your logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just read the file content into memory first?
There is no need to first load text from a file into a RichTextBox and then try to complicatedly extract it out of there.

If you absolutely need to do that, RichTextBox control contains a Lines property.
([see here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: I wasn't able to find a method doing that if that's easier I'd appreciate it if you'd tell me how to do that and how to implement that into my current code.